# Images fades into each other in slider

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a jQuery slider. Currently, the images are fading out, and then the next image in the slider fades in. But what I would need, is the images the be fading into each other. So I won't see the page background during the transition.

Here's my jQuery code :

```
$('.slider .slide:first').addClass('active').fadeIn(900);

function rotate(index) {
     $('.slider .slide.active').removeClass('active').fadeOut(900, function() {
         $('.slider .slide:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active').fadeIn(900);
     });   
}

$('.slider-nav li').click(function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    $(this).siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var index = $(this).index('li');
    rotate(index);
    timer=setInterval(go, 5000);
    return false;
});
$('.slider-nav li:first').click();
var timer=setInterval(go, 5000);
function go() {
    var $next = $('.slider-nav li.active').next();
    if ($next.length == 0){
        $next = $('.slider-nav li:first');
    }
    $next.click();
}
```

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your own fadeIn - as far as I understand it, you'll need to fadeIn both at the same time, which might work sort of hackishly with jQuery's, but, it will be easier if you just write a simple function that fades them in simultaneously (i.e. pull down opacity one after another over several hundred iterations).

Comment: So I guess I should add a `delay` or something like that?

Comment: Isn't .animate for CSS properties? I'm not sure to understand.

Comment: You're doing something similar to animate - a delay would be fine.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how it would work using my code please? I'm new to jQuery and I'm really not sure how to do this